# A question about installing security updates

Tags: updates, package-management, security

I'm always following a website to know when security updates for Ubuntu are available.

But, today, I saw this update (http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2388-1/), but the website told me to update the system to some packages. But I don't know how to do that.

Do I have to just use the update manager and install the updates? Or maybe do another thing?

Thank you guys for helping me.

PS: I already updated using the update manager and tested if there was any apt-get update and upgrade available (there weren't any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is a server, there is a server updating program in the repositories you can use that will apply updates automatically:

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

If you use a desktop system, applying the updates via GUI is sufficient. You can choose the regularity of updating in the system settings, e.g. "apply security updates daily".

Comment: Just to know, when you said GUI, it's the update manager?

Comment: Yes. I use "check for updates daily", "display security updates immediately" and "display other updates weekly". Works like a charm.